# Change friends icon/avatar on Google Latitude

Tags: google-maps, google-latitude

I recently started using Google Latitude with some of my close friends. Many of them have not set a picture for their icon/avatar yet, so when looking at a map it can be difficult to identify people (They all have the default silhouette icon). Is there any way for me to change the icon that is displayed for one of my friends?

I already tried changing the picture associated with their email address in my Gmail account, and that did not work. Any other suggestions other than nagging them to change it themselves?

Comment: Looks like you're stuck with nagging them to change it since Latitude doesn't appear to make use of Contacts information.